# Программа выдает ошибку TypeError: load_model() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, pycharm, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

в pycharm при вызове

> from tensorflow.python.keras.models import load_model

> mod = load_model('C:\project\detected_trend.h5')

выдает ошибку TypeError: load_model() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

при аналогичном запуске в anaconda navigator все работает нормально.

Comment: А у вас там нет случайно в коде свой функции с таким же названием load_model?

Comment: кажется я идиот)

Comment: Не переживайте, это типичная ошибка в питоне - перекрыть библиотечную или встроенную функцию своей функцией или переменной )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оформлю, пожалуй, ответом, вдруг кому пригодится.

Если вы видите странную ошибку, говорящую вам, что вы вызываете библиотечную или встроенную функцию как-то неправильно, хотя согласно документации вы должны её вызывать именно так - с тем набором аргументов, с которым вы её вызываете, то проверьте ваш код, возможно, вы описали в нём свою функцию (или переменную, но тогда ошибка будет другая) с точно таким же названием.

В питоне это довольно типичная проблема, вы можете перекрыть своей функцией или переменной встроенную или загруженную из библиотеки функцию и узнаете об этом только по странной ошибке в момент вызова этой функции. В компилируемых языках такие проблемы обычно выявляются уже на этапе компиляции, компилятор вам так просто не даст назвать одинаково разные сущности.